Level sets and critical points of a function
One of my homework assignments (already turned in) was to solve the following problem:

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 2}$ and $\boldsymbol{a}, \boldsymbol{b} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\boldsymbol{a} \neq \boldsymbol{b}$. Find the critical points of $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$
f(\boldsymbol{x}) = \frac{1}{\| \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{a} \|_2} + \frac{1}{\| \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{b} \|_2}
$$

A hint was provided that I should look at level sets. Unfortunately, my proof is quite long (it took two full A4 pages) and I assume that there might be a more elegant and shorter solution. How to do it better?
The sketch of my approach to the problem was the following:

Assume, without loss of generality (because we're in an affine space), that $\boldsymbol{a} = \boldsymbol{0}$.
Define two sets: $A(r) = \{ \boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \, : \, \| \boldsymbol{x} \|_2 = r \}$ and $B(r) = \{ \boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \, : \, \| \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{b} \|_2 = r \}$ for $r > 0$. Note that for a fixed $r_B > 0$, the sets $A(r_A)$ and $B(r_B)$ have a non-empty intersection if and only if $\| \boldsymbol{b} \|_2 - r_B \le r_A \le \| \boldsymbol{b} \|_2 + r_B$.
Fix $r_B > 0$. Let $C(r_B) = \{ r_A > 0 \, : \, \| \boldsymbol{b} \|_2 - r_B \le r_A \le \| \boldsymbol{b} \|_2 + r_B \}$ and let $r_A, r'_A \in \mathrm{int} \, C(r_B)$ be distinct. Let $\boldsymbol{x} \in A(r_A) \cap B(r_B)$ and $\boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{h} \in A(r'_A) \cap B(r_B)$. Let $\mathcal{S} = \mathrm{span} \{ \boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{h} \} \cap \mathrm{int} \, C(r_B)$.
Using the law of cosines (we're considering a Euclidean norm), show that $f(\boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{h}) - f(\boldsymbol{x})$ is not $o(\| \boldsymbol{h} \|)$, which means that $Df(\boldsymbol{x}) \neq \boldsymbol{0}$, so $\boldsymbol{x}$ cannot be a critical point of $f$.
If a critical point of $f$ exists, it must be a tangent point of spheres $A(r_A)$ and $B(r_B)$. We show that sphere $A(r_A)$ cannot be inside sphere $B(r_B)$, so the only candidate for a critical point is the point $\boldsymbol{x} = \frac{1 - r_B}{r_B} \boldsymbol{b}$.
We show that for such a point, $Df(\boldsymbol{x}) = \boldsymbol{0}$ if and only if $r_B = \frac{1}{2} \| \boldsymbol{b} \|_2$, and that's the only critical point of $f$.


$f$ is the superposition of two potentials whose gradients can be viewed as forces repelling test particles. Use symmetry to find the only point at which these forces cancel.

attracting test particles is probably better.

I see, that makes a lot sense. Gradient is a linear map and since the gradient at a point is tangent to the level set of that point, and since the level sets of each of those two terms are very simple sets, easy to analyse, it all simplifies a lot. Thank you!

The gradient is not tangent to the level sets. It is orthogonal to them.
